# How to configure jenkins to send gitlab commit messages?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I want to pull git commit message in jenkins and send them in an email which jenkins sends for successful build.

As per search, Git changelog plugin can be used for this. But I am not sure how should we configure it. Any answer with example would help me out.

I have added the Git changelog plugin in the jenkins. Tried few settings but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the message inside a variable and then you can send it over mail using a condition as shown below:-

```
stage('Git Commit Message') {
    agent { node { label 'Linux' } }
        steps {
            script {
                result = sh (script: "git log --format=%B -n 1 COMMIT_ID", returnStdout: true)
                // After this you can put condition for if your build is scccessful and send "result" variable in mail
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
post {
        always {
            mail bcc: '', body: "A commit has been done \n
            status : $ {currentBuild.currentResult}: \n Job 
            {env.JOb_NAME}\n build
                    ${enb.BUILD_NUMBER} \n for detail: ${env.BUILD_URL}\n 
            Any action?",
                    cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: "Report 
             ${env.BUILD_ID}", to: 'johnsmith@abc.com'
    }
```